# Copy file to remote location in Python

Tags: python, share

```
copy testfile.txt \\\\IP_ADDR\\FOLDER
```

works in command line but :

```
os.system("copy testfile.txt \\\\IP_ADDR\\FOLDER")
```

doesnt work somehow. Any ideas?

there is a replacement for `os.system` but why doesn't this do the trick?

Answer (score 6):

I think you either need to double up your backslashes or place 'r' in front of the string:

```
os.system("copy testfile.txt \\\\\\\\IP_ADDR\\\\FOLDER")

os.system(r"copy testfile.txt \\\\IP_ADDR\\FOLDER")
```